# "authentication_error" while signing up using pouchdb

Tags: pouchdb

I am using pouchDb with couchbase server. I am creating a demo login and signing app. While testing the PouchDB's signup method I got the error

> "authentication_error".

I have logged the error in browser's console. I have attached the signup method

```
/** Function to signup User starts * */
function signUpUser() {
    db.signup('superman', 'clarkkent', function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.name === 'conflict') {
                console.log("User already exists, choose another username");
            } else if (err.name === 'forbidden') {
                console.log("invalid username");
            } else {
                console.log(err.name);
            }
        }
    });
}
/** Function to signup User ends * */
```

Comment: Is this "db" variable the local PouchDB database instance, or it is instance to the remote CouchDB using PouchDB?

Comment: Its a PouchDB variabel

Comment: Then this will not gonna work. Local PouchDB does not have login system built in. You have to develop it yourself.
Check here about requirements on PouchDB Atuhentication plugin you are using:
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#requirements

Answer (score 0):

The pouchdb-authentication plugin only works with CouchDB, not with Couchbase Server.

Comment: Can I write custom using map reduce to signup or login?